# Xamarin.iOS Can I use PlacePicker in my iOS application

Tags: xamarin.ios, gmsplacepicker

how can I implement PlacePicker in my project as I can this doable in iOS native by implement this code

```
@IBAction func pickPlace(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
  let placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

  placePicker.pickPlace(callback: { (place, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
      print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      return
    }

    guard let place = place else {
      print("No place selected")
      return
    }

    print("Place name \(place.name)")
    print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
  })
}
```

how can I do the same in Xamarin.iOS

**First** I need  nuget to include in my project

**Second**  how can I implement the same code

Answer (score 0):

First follow [instruction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) to get google api key

Second Call this method in `FinishedLaunching`

```
string googleApiKey = YOUR_KEY_HERE;

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
 ConfigureGoogleMaps();
        }

 void ConfigureGoogleMaps()
        {
            PlacesClient.ProvideApiKey(googleApiKey);
            MapServices.ProvideAPIKey(googleApiKey);
        }
```

Third add this keys in your `Info.plist`

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

Fourth ask user for permission to use his location `Info.plist`

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application requires location services to work</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This application requires location services to work</string>
```

Fifth now we call **PlacePicker**

```
var config = new PlacePickerConfig(null);
            var placePicker = new PlacePicker(config);
            placePicker.PickPlaceWithCallback((result, error) => {

                if(error != null){
                    return;    
                }
                if(result != null){
                    SelectedPlace = result;
                    street.Text = result.FormattedAddress;   
                }

            });
```

If you want know what equivalent to any method name in native looking **[here](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/Google.Maps/source/Google.Maps/ApiDefinition.cs)**